# loadUrl(): Load two images - JQuery

Tags: jquery, image, layer

I am using this layer Script: [Click](http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/).

And now I want to display in the layer two images which were selected by a checkbox:

```
$('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
    content:'image', //'ajax', 'iframe' or 'image'
    contentContainer:'.content',
    loadUrl: 'upload/'+selected[0]+'',
    loadUrl: 'upload/'+selected[1]+''
});
```

With one image everything works perfect. But when I add the second image nothing works.

Note: selected[] is the variable of the selected images.

Thank you for all answers.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of your object is probably the issue (you can have two fields with the same name[loadUrl]). Try it this way:

```
        $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
            content:'image', //'ajax', 'iframe' or 'image'
            contentContainer:'.content',
            loadUrl: [
                'upload/' + selected[0] + '',
                'upload/' + selected[1] + ''
            ]
        });
```

Your urls field should be an array of strings.